# Is "expectation" correct? "...expectation for things we don't know yet about"

Tags: grammar, word-usage

> A looming sense of unease from a tiny bit of expectation for (or of?) things we don't know yet about.

I am a foreigner and would like to add this phrase in one of my texts; however, I feel like it is a bit off. Could let me know if it looks alright, and if not, where could I improve?

Comment: Is the for/of choice the only part that feels a 'bit off'?

Comment: I don't think you can _expect_ something whose nature is unknown.

Comment: '...a sense of foreboding.'

Answer (score 1):

> expectation = the feeling of expecting something to happen
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/expectation)

Your sentence thus means
"*... a looming sense of unease from a tiny bit of ***the feeling of expecting something*** ***to happen****." The *something* is "things we don't know yet about".

Or, with my parenthetic explanatory comments:

"*... a looming sense of unease* (that comes) *from a tiny bit of ***the feeling of expecting something**** (we don't yet know what but we fear it will be nasty, hence our unease) ***to happen***.